# Passing post value with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this code in my index.php:

```
 $('#whois').click(function () {
        //console.log("button clicked");
            $('#whois_content').html("");
            $('#fade').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                urlLinkas();
            });
        });
```

I want to pass a post value to test.php inside this script, like so:

```
 $('#whois').click(function () {
        //console.log("button clicked");
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(){
        //dont know what to write here
        }
            $('#whois_content').html("");
            $('#fade').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                urlLinkas();
            });
        });
```

And then call this post value in test.php `$_POST['info']`

Maybe someone will understand what im saying.

Comment: what is info variable it is not defined?

Comment: Maybe, you'll provide a question? P.S.: try `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: define the 'datatype' and try

Comment: What is the problem? What is your question? and where `info` defined in `data:info` ?

Comment: There is no question in this post, and thus no problem to solve.  This makes it very difficult for other people trying to search for solutions to problems.

Answer (score 1):

this would be better

```
$.post("test.php", { info: "Something", moreinfo: "Something Else" })
.done(function(data) {
    $('#whois_content').html("");
    $('#fade').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        urlLinkas();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work , try it out:

```
$('#whois').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {info: "some info"},
        success: function () {

        }
        $('#whois_content').html("");
    $('#fade').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        urlLinkas();
    });
});
```